# Use Ushahidi api in another map using openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, api, ushahidi

I have a ushahidi deployment and i am using Openlayers + ushahidi api to show the reports in a separate map along with other features.

i have queried the data from ushahidi api and made a vector layer. the layer has data but it not showing up.

This part gets the data from ushahidi

```
var roadreportrequest = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
url: '../roadreport/api/?task=incidents',
async: false,
success: function(Request) {
    // alert("success");
    roadreportjson = JSON.parse(Request.responseText);
},
failure: function() {
    alert("failed to load data from roadrepoter");
    roadreportjson = {}
}
```

});

and this part converts it to vector layer

```
var roadreport_vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('RoadReporter Reports');

for (incident_index in roadreportjson.payload.incidents) {
// console.log(incident_index, roadreportjson.payload.incidents[incident_index]);
incident = roadreportjson.payload.incidents[incident_index];
roadreport_vector.addFeatures([
    new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(incident.incident.locationlongitude, incident.incident.locationlatitude),
        incident)
])
}
map.addLayer(roadreport_vector);
```

There is data in the layer, i have checked the console and this code to pan the map also works.

```
map.panTo(new OpenLayers.LonLat(roadreport_vector.features[2].geometry.x, roadreport_vector.features[2].geometry.y))
```

My issue is that i am expecting the data to be shown up as on the map(the default orange circles), but it is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a matter of different Projection systems. Ushahidid stores and returns data in wgs 84(EPSG;4326) system whereas the map was on spherical mercator system (EPSG:900913).